# Installation of full-text research on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, full-text-search

I may need some assistance for my installation of FTS on my computer.
I have the requirement of practicing some stuff concerning FTS.
And at the beginning, I used **SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled');** to check if FTS was installed on my desktop and the result was 0.
Then I started to find the solution by asking Professor Goo (Google), yet I still haven't found a solution that can resolve my problem after seeing some articles for approximately one hour.

And the followings are some information

[image: Version of SQL server]

[image: NoOptionforFTS]

Any suggestion, please.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer and I'll answer to myself though it may be kind of idiotic for asking this. Well, what I had in my hand is 'ENU\x64\SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe' and, a person should download Express with Advanced Services(ENU\x64\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe) and thne add the feature, like FTS, to the existing instance or the new one. In the end, the person can start to explore the functions provided by FTS.